# Data modeling in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I'm creating my website with node.js(express.js) and I have one question about mongodb and mongoose.
This question is how to make schema for my collection? For example I have users on my webiste, and user can subscribe for another user? How to write schema for this?
For now I have something like this:

```
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will allow you to add things to the database via the schema. (Very idiomatically, the database will be called 'users', as Mongoose pluralises the first argument for you.)

```
mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

There are a couple of ways to add things to the database - I use promises, which requires you to call this before you connect (I think it has to be before?)

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

You can then save new instances of the schema:

```
new User ({
  username: 'me',
  password: 'dontlooknow',
}).save()
```

Save returns a promise, so you can follow it with a .then() after if you want. You can do it with callbacks too if you prefer, just look at the docs. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html.